# How to create empty-conditional operator for collections similar to null-conditional operator?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable, c#-6.0, null-conditional-operator

C# 6.0 introduced null-conditional operator, a big win.

Now I would like to have an operator which behaves similarly to it, but for empty collections.

```
Region smallestFittingFreeRegion = FreeRegions
            .Where(region => region.Rect.W >= width && region.Rect.H >= height)                
            .MinBy(region => (region.Rect.W - width) * (region.Rect.H - height));
```

Now this blows up if `Where` returns an empty `IEnumerable`, because `MinBy` (from `MoreLinq`) throws an exception if collection is empty.

Before C# 6.0 this would probably be solved by adding another *extension method* `MinByOrDefault`.

I would like to re-write it like this: `.Where(...)?.MinBy(...)`. But this doesn't work because `.Where` returns an *empty collection* instead of `null`.

Now this could be solved by introducing a `.NullIfEmpty()` extension method for `IEnumerable`. Arriving at `.Where(...).NullIfEmpty()?.MinBy()`.

Ultimately this seems awkward because returning *empty collection* has always been preferable to returning a `null`.

**Is there an other more-elegant way to do this?**

Comment: I assume you would not call using `Any` in an `if` statement "elegant"?

Comment: You've proposed two simple solutions that are compact and easy to understand.  How much more elegant do you want?

Comment: Have you tried this? `.DefaultIfEmpty().MinBy(region => (region?.Rect?.W - width) * (region?.Rect?.H - height))`

Comment: D Stanley, stackoverflow users often surprise me with their ingenuity.

Comment: An empty enumerable is a perfectly valid enumerable and shouldn't need any kind of special treatment, *unlike* null whose meaning is ambiguous and doesn't allow any valid operation. Your issue is really with the `MinBy` method's requirement for a non-empty input. Besides, *what* would you want `MinBy` to return if there are no matching elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, the "most elegent" solution is to re-write [`MinBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) to make it in to a MinByOrDefault

```
public static TSource MinByOrDefault<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{
    return source.MinByOrDefault(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
}

public static TSource MinByOrDefault<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
    if (comparer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");
    using (var sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            return default(TSource); //This is the only line changed.
        }
        var min = sourceIterator.Current;
        var minKey = selector(min);
        while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            var candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
            var candidateProjected = selector(candidate);
            if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, minKey) < 0)
            {
                min = candidate;
                minKey = candidateProjected;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

I don't see much need for a special operator.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `DefaultIfEmtpy` to define a default item to put in the sequence if it's empty:

```
Region smallestFittingFreeRegion = FreeRegions
    .Where(region => region.Rect.W >= width && region.Rect.H >= height) 
    .DefaultIfEmpty()               
    .MinBy(region => (region.Rect.W - width) * (region.Rect.H - height));
```

And of course you can use the overload accepting a second parameter if you want to provide your own default value to use in the event that the type's default value isn't what you want.

Comment: This does not work if region is reference type, as that will lead to null pointer exception in .MinBy.

Comment: @JBeurer As I said, you can pass whatever default value you want to use, if that's what you want to do.